# Shrink my .mdf file in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a 10 GB `.mdf` file with 250 mb `.LDF`.

I want to shrink the 10 GB `.mdf` (if possible)

I read about the dbcc command, but I read it in context of shrinking the `.LDF` (into any size desired using truncate).

However I want to shrink the `.MDF` file without loosing data.

What is the precise command for it ?

Comment: Do you know *why* you want to do this?

Comment: @gbn ,Im building a hash / scramble mechanism which takes a bak  - hash it - and saves it. I really dont need to deal with the LDF here...

Comment: I dont understand why this question was downrated .  it is a valid question. if its bad practice - so the action is to responde why is it bad practice and not to downvote.... people dont know the meaning of downvote here...@marc_s ... was that you ? :)

Comment: So are you trying to do your own back up solution? BTW I didn't downvote

Comment: Here - I found the link I was looking for - Paul Randal's blog post [Why you should not shrink your data files](http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/Why-you-should-not-shrink-your-data-files.aspx) - read it, embrace it - don't shrink your MDF's - it's pointless and counter productive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply answer:

```
DBCC SHRINKFILE('DB filename', 10240)
```

**OR** for MDF file

```
DBCC SHRINKFILE(1, 10240)
```

But if you have more than 10240 Mb of data in MDF file - it woun't help, then you have to add extra file to DB - where to move extra data from MDF file.

From BOL:

> DBCC SHRINKFILE
>
> Shrinks the size of the specified data or log file for the current database or empties a file by moving the data from the specified file
>   to other files in the same filegroup, allowing the file to be removed
>   from the database. You can shrink a file to a size that is less than
>   the size specified when it was created. This resets the minimum file
>   size to the new value.

How to know filenames in DB:

```
SELECT file_Id, name FROM sys.database_files
```

**Shrinking data files always affects performance - it makes it worse, so you really need to have a *REASON* to do that.**

Comment: `DBCC SHRINKFILE(1, 10240)` where is the db param goes here ?

Comment: Use this in context of the DB, which the file you want to shrink

Comment: does `10240` is calculated or just a upper margin limit ? If I have 10 GB dB , What should i use ? is it in KB ? MB ?

Comment: ,Im building a hash / scramble mechanism which takes a bak - hash it - and saves it. I really dont need to deal with the LDF here...

Comment: 10240 - this parameter is in MB, you cannot avoid using LDF file EXCEPT - your database is in READONLY MODE

Answer (score 0):

To shrink your database log:

```
ALTER DATABASE [your db name] SET RECOVERY SIMPLE WITH NO_WAIT
DBCC SHRINKFILE(N'file name ', 1)
ALTER DATABASE [your db name] SET RECOVERY FULL WITH NO_WAIT
```